# using indexOf() to compose an array of unique values

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

I'm iterating through an XML. One of the child elements is `GroupName`, which is not unique in the XML string/file. Therefor, I'm trying to put the different (unique) occurrences of the *innertext*, if you will, of these `GroupName` tags in an array.

```
<GroupName></GroupName>
<GroupName></GroupName>
<GroupName>VIII</GroupName>
<GroupName>Date and signature</GroupName>
<GroupName>Date and signature</GroupName>
<GroupName>Date and signature</GroupName>
<GroupName>Date and signature</GroupName>
<GroupName>VII</GroupName>
```

In this particular case, `GroupNames` are [empty string], 'VII', 'VIII' and 'Date and signature'.

When I use jQuery to alert ALL the `GroupNames`, all are shown:

```
$xmlDoc.find('GroupName').each(function () {
    alert($(this).text();
});
```

However, when I try to use `indexOf()` to compose an array of unique values, one of them seems to get skipped!

```
$xmlDoc.find('GroupName').each(function () {
$groupName = ($(this).text().length == 0) ? 'empty' : $(this).text();
    if (groupnames.indexOf($groupName) < 0) {
        groupnames.push($groupName);
    }
});
```

In this case, I get 'empty', 'VIII' and 'Date and signature'. 'VII' is, somehow, lost and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Can you post your XML?

Comment: can you set an `alert($(this).text())` inside the `each` function and verify that "VII" gets alerted? (or output to console, or set a breakpoint - either or)

Comment: $groupName should be local within your function - try "var $groupName"  instead of just "$groupName"

Comment: nm, I'm an idiot... I was skipping the last element of the array.

Comment: It seems to be fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wxfbM/

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < groupnames.length - 1; i++)` ... that wasn't smart.

Comment: check an updated version at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wxfbM/2/

Comment: not all browser versions support "indexOf" function for Array...(IE) use JQuery "inArray" function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/ ...